# Extracting data from JSON and modifying data

Tags: java, json

I want to extract jkl object from below JSON string. Also after extraction, I want the backslashes to be removed and extract further with the braces. I followed few questions on StackOverflow but it didn't help much.

```
{
 "abc:def": {
      "ghi": {
         "jkl": "{\"mno:pqr\":{\"ty\":4,\"\\nsensing_service_name:\\\"Number\\\",\\nsensing_service_id: 20\\n}\\n     ]\\n}\"}}",
         "st": {
            "op": 5,
            "org": "q9wr9qrq"
         },
         "uvw": 1
      },
      "xyz": false
   }
}
```

I tried below code to display jkl object but it is not working. Please suggest what is wrong in this and how to correct the same

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(data);
JSONObject aa = json.getJSONObject("abc:def");
JSONObject bb = aa.getJSONObject("ghi");
JSONObject cc = bb.getJSONObject("jkl");
System.out.println(cc);
```

Comment: The problem is you're trying to get a string as a JSONObject.

Comment: what do you want to show?

Comment: Thanks. I want to show value of nsensing_service_name

Comment: @pravin what is data-type of JSONObject? and is JSONSerializer from flexjson.JSONSerializer ?

Comment: jkl is not a valid Json Object, so bb.getJSONObject("jkl") is giving you exception, you might want to look at your input data json

Comment: yes, checked the same. Thanks for your valuable comments @prasshant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonString = "{\n" +
                " \"abc:def\": {\n" +
                "      \"ghi\": {\n" +
                "         \"jkl\": \"{\\\"mno:pqr\\\":{\\\"ty\\\":4,\\\"\\\\nsensing_service_name:\\\\\\\"Number\\\\\\\",\\\\nsensing_service_id: 20\\\\n}\\\\n     ]\\\\n}\\\"}}\",\n" +
                "         \"st\": {\n" +
                "            \"op\": 5,\n" +
                "            \"org\": \"q9wr9qrq\"\n" +
                "         },\n" +
                "         \"uvw\": 1\n" +
                "      },\n" +
                "      \"xyz\": false\n" +
                "   }\n" +
                "} ";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("abc:def");
        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("ghi");
        String result = jsonObject.getString("jkl");
        result = StringUtils.replace(result, "\\n", "");
        System.out.println(result.replaceAll("\\\\",""));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudha. It is working as expected. I think it was the mistake pointed out by @shmosel that I was doing.